# What is the best way to refer to a model API from a view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I really hate singletons and would like to know if there is a better and cleaner way to pass a model reference to a view controller so I could use it's API.

Comment: what is the model reference? Are you having trouble defining a @protocol or having trouble telling the view controller about the instance?

Comment: Elaborate a bit...er, a lot. You've got a lot of space left for a more complete/specific question.

Comment: the question is a general architectural question, I don't have a specific example that need solving.

Comment: You can a: use a singleton to reference a model object which you intend to have only one of, b: reference a collection of (or single) instances which you have passed or fetched in the controller, or c: use class methods to access api methods belonging to the object and not the instance.  You can be as clever as you like about it, but those are your choices.

Answer (score -1):

Dont hate singletons, just learn to use them where they are appropriate.

That said, if you don't want to use a singleton you can instantiate your model controller in your app delegate or a 'root' view controller and then pass the reference to all of the view controllers which need it (just like you would pass any other configuration data).

---

On singletons, they are appropriate when you have some content which should only exist once and it needs to exist for the lifetime of the app. This state would also usually be shared between multiple areas of the app. Singletons obviously aren't the only choice but in an Object Oriented language it makes sense to have an instantiated object to own and manage particular state and knowledge.

People often abuse the app delegate and give it a number of inappropriate responsibilities, using a singleton would provide a better app structure.

Comment: And which would be the fabled "appropriate place for singletons"?

Comment: @tereško, I've added some more info. Singletons can obviously be abused too but they do have their uses and a rightful place in the world.